# Monotouch Dynamically append record to UItableview

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios

I come across a problem in monotouch I am feting 20 records from web service at a time.
initially my tablview show 20 record.
now when user scroll and come to end of the page may be on 17th row I want to call web service 
and fetch but I failed to find such event in UITableViewDelegate.

I am confuse which method I should override to hook event.

Please help me to fix this issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- In `UITableViewSource` (which is combination of `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource` in MonoTouch) when iOS called `GetCell` method, check for `indexPath` and if it's greater than 16, call server's method;
- Other solution is to override `Scrolled` method (cause `UITableView` is subclass of `UIScrollView`) and check that user scrolled to desirable `UITableViewCell` coordinate via `scrollView.ContentOffset.Y`.

Note that to reach better user experience I recommend you to add new rows to `UITableView` via `InsertRows` method plus updating `UITableViewSource` rather than updating `UITableViewSource` and calling `UITableView.ReloadData()`.

Comment: hey thanks for answer, currently I using approach 1 but again how do I update My UITableViewDataSource as well as UITableViewDelegate because in mono touch I have crate two different class derived from  UITableViewDataSource  and UITableViewDelegate as I am using approach 1 I getting data under GetCell method in datasource class, how should I update table rows as well as same result should be reflect to deleget class

Comment: Imagine, you store `UITableViewDataSource` data in a `List`. When you received 10 new rows from server, add them to the end of a `List`, then call `UITableView.InsertRows` with array of `NSIndexPath` of new rows.